# Length of forms in ArcPad10

Tags: gps, arcpad

I'm trying to create a survey with about 250 questions in ArcPad 10. Normally you would expect that a form you created in any application will be able to scroll in PDA if it is too long.  But the custom forms I create in ArcPad 10 just ignores the extra fields and doesn't scroll to them.
Did anyone come across this?

Thanks

Comment: What method did you use to create the form? I've never made one that long; in the worst case, you could use some scripting to deliver the form as consecutive smaller chunks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Forms in ArcPad are only ever as large as the screen size.  Painful but true.  The typical solution is to create multiple pages, so you have to use the tabs to get to additional input.  Horrid from a UI standpoint, but sadly that's what you're stuck with.

You also can't implement manual scrolling, as the API doesn't allow you to dynamically set input/label positions.

Answer (score 2):

It depends on the device and which version of Windows Mobile you are using. If you can't get a scroll bar appearing on your device, you will need to match your forms to the resolution of your screen and use multiple pages to input your data. For an example of this, check out your geodatabase data using ArcPad Data Manager in ArcMap and it will auto-create forms for you.

Comment: Can you tell us what device/WM version provides scroll bars on forms?

Comment: I know it works on the Juniper Mesa running WM 6.5, i don't have a complete list, but I'm working on it!!

Answer (score 0):

The old versions of Trimble GPSs leaves you with no choice but to limit the values in each screen whereas that is not the case with the latest gadgets,the scroll bars are available, others use buttons to overcome this problem,i haven't tried though so i always prefer limiting my fields per screen